# Sinatra not passing session variable?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following code:

```
enable :sessions
class CSFSWC < Sinatra::Application

post '/login' do

  username = params[:username]
  password = params[:password]

if csfsss.authenticate(username,password) == false
  redirect '/'
  # session[:loginsession] = nil
else
  # Start session here
  session[:username] = params[:username]
  @sessionID = session[:username]
  puts "Session : #{@sessionID}"
  redirect '/main'
end

get '/main' do
 puts "main session : #{@sessionID}"
end
```

In /main the puts print out a empty session[:username]. 
Any ideas? As far as I understand sessions in Sinatra according to: [Sinatra Sessions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions).

It should just work.

In fact even if I copy the example from [Sinatra Sessions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions)

```
class CSFSWC < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions

  get '/foo' do
    session[:message] = 'Hello World!'
    puts "foo : #{session[:message]}"
    redirect '/bar'
  end

  get '/bar' do
    puts "bar : #{session[:message]}"
  end
```

It still does not work?

Comment: i'm pretty sure, instance variables aren't available in the next (redirected) request. try accessing `session[:username]` within `get '/main'`

Comment: Same thing problem with this puts "main session : #{session[:username]}"in /main

Answer (score 1):

It's working just fine - look at your app's output to the console. It's just not doing what you expect. `puts` writes to stdout, not to the browser. With Sinatra, the last string you return is what is sent to the browser. This is what you want:

```
class CSFSWC < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions

  get '/foo' do
    session[:message] = 'Hello World!'
    # This just writes it to your log
    puts "foo : #{session[:message]}"
    redirect '/bar'
  end

  get '/bar' do
    "bar : #{session[:message]}"
  end
end
```